# Graphics Driver for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, command-line

Hello I am new to Ubuntu and I am having problems locating the graphics driver to install. I have a Pentium 4 HT 3.2 dual core, I tried the command jockey-kde but found out that is for an AMD 64 processor. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: The "amd64" naming is misleading -- it refers to all 64-bit chips including those made by intel. If you have a 64-bit chip and a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, the "amd64" version of the driver is one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try Intel Linux Graphics Installer provided by Intel at this link [HERE](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer)

I hope that helps.